# view custom properties on entity framework edmx designer

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I added a custom property to a partial class like so:

```
public partial class Survey
{
public IEnumerable<BODSurveys.SurveysAnwer> answers
  {
   get;
   set;
  }
}
```

what can I do to be able to see the custom property in the designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing. EDMX designer shows only mapped properties defined in its internal structure. It doesn't see what you did in class.